# create a new branch from local version(started from master)

Tags: git

I use GIT for versioning. I started from the master branch and I made local development without switching to a new branch (serious error of beginner but whatever) .
My question is how to create a new branch and push the version I have in local on it without changing the branch master and without losing my dev in local(I point to master branch but did'nt push anything on it)? 
In other words, from which branch I should create the new branch? and how not to lose my development that are still in local?

Comment: Have you made any commit?

Comment: @leopal I didn't made any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new branch from the local master branch, and push the new branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

if you have commits

```
git push origin new_brach  
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

else

```
git commit -am "commit message" 
git push origin new_brach
```

Comment: He might need to commit between checkout and push.